# How create an array using libjson?

Tags: c++, arrays, json, libjson

I want to make an array with libJSON's `JSONNode`. I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
JSONNode array;
JSONNode foo("word", "foo");
JSONNode bar("word", "bar");
array.push_back(foo);
array.push_back(bar);
```

This results in:

```
{ 
    "word": "foo", 
    "word": "bar"
}
```

What I want is:

```
[
    {"word": "foo"},
    {"word": "bar"}
]
```

It's clear to me that I'm not specifying that I want an array. The thing is, I've searched the library and googled a bit, but I find no way to do this. Can anybody help me out with this?

(Sidenote: I wanted to add a "libjson" tag, but that doesn't exist yet, it seems.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify that you're creating an array and complex nodes:

```
JSONNode array(JSON_ARRAY);
JSONNode foo(JSON_NODE);
JSONNode bar(JSON_NODE);

foo.push_back(JSONNode("word", "foo"));
bar.push_back(JSONNode("word", "bar"));

array.push_back(foo);
array.push_back(bar);
```

See the "Getting Started" documentation in `libjson-VERSION.zip` for some basic examples.

*Side note: I've personally found libjson to be annoying to work with, and the documentation is severely lacking. In my own projects, I use either [JsonCpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net) or (more frequently) [Jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson) as my C/C++ JSON API. If you're not locked in to libjson, you might give them a try.*

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm seeing a pattern in how obvious all the answers to my questions are. :(

Comment: what do you consider the best c++ json now?